# Many to Many with thousands of reference items

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I currently have a SQL Server database with a table containing 400,000 movies. I have another table containing thousands of users.

```
CREATE TABLE [movie].[Header]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SourceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseDate] [Date] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [account].[Registration]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [movie].[Likes] 
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [HeaderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [movie].[Dislikes]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [HeaderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
```

Each user is shown 100 movies starting from two weeks into the future. They can then perform an action such as like, dislike, recommend etc.

I'm in the process of moving the entire application into a serverless architecture. I have the APIs running in AWS via Lambda + API Gateway and now I'm looking at using DynamoDB for the database. I don't think I have anything super crazy that would prevent me from storing the data in Dynamo and their pricing/consumption model seems like it would be substantially cheaper than SQL Server (currently hosted in Azure).

The one thing I'm having issues with is understanding how I would model the users performing an action on a movie. If they "like" a movie, it goes into a likes list that they can go back and visit. There, I present them the entire move record (which actually consists of more data such as cast/crew/ratings etc. I just truncated the cable to simplify it). If I stored each "Like" as an item in Dynamo, along with the entire movie as an attribute, I'd think that the users document would get very large.

I also need to continue to show users movies, starting two weeks out, that they have not performed any actions on. Movies that they have performed actions on I need to remove from the query. Today I'm just joining on the movies table and the users actions table, removing movies from the query that already exists in the users action table. How would I model this in NoSql with the same end-result?

I can consolidate the likes/dislikes into a single document with an action type attribute (representing like/dislike etc), and an array of movies that the action has been performed on. Not sure still how I would go about filtering the `[Header]` query so that the movies in the users document don't come back.

I figured I would set my movies hash key to the release date for sharding, since there's roughly 10 movies per release date on average. That gives a nice distribution. I figured I'd use the userid has the hash key for the document containing all of the movies that a user has performed an action on; not sure if that's the right path though.

I've never dealt with NoSql so I wanted to ask for input. I am not sure how best to design something that is essentially one-to-many, but with the potential for the movies-per-user being in the tens of thousands.

Comment: Dynamodb is really about understanding your data access patterns. Such like, what is the mostly used queries, what is written or read in bulk rather than lightly distributed over time... I can think if some answers to your question but they are no good if I dont know answers to these questions. For example, is users getting listed of not-yet-liked/disliked movies much more frequent than getting list of already-liked moves. On average how many items to be returned from these queries each? DynamoDB is mainly about making good TRADE-OFFS. By the way 'document' isnt a dynamoDB term :)

Comment: In short can you tell more about what is more important / heavy for you. What could be your trade-offs

Comment: The queries most used are queries to display a list of movies that the users haven't already liked/disliked, along with all of the cast and crew of the movie (can be 60 people) along with movie details (rating, genres, description etc). The 2nd query is all movies that the users have liked/disliked. Currently it's a separate query for likes and another dislikes. That seems like something i could easily combine though. The likes/dislikes query presents the user with all of the cast/crew and movie details as well.

Comment: Currently we have 400,000 movies. Multiply that by cast/crew records and it's a decent amount of data to try copying around. Idk if I should keep a table of movies, then a table of users with attributes representing all of the likes/dislikes. We've seen users like/dislike in some cases 1,000 movies in a single day, so that would bring up pagination needs when within the app.

Answer (score 3):

So, based on your comments I am gonna throw in a suggestion. It doesn't mean its a right answer, I could be wrong as well or missing a point

First of all please read every segment of the [Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html) over and over again. There are patterns that you might never thought of but is still possible with NoSQL approach. Its very helpful and educative (considering you saying you are new to NoSQL). There are similarities to your case and you might create your own answer based on the best practices.

What I can suggest is:

NoSQL is very bad at querying for 'not existing'. A big trick of NoSQL is it exactly knows where to find the data you are looking for, not where not not to find. So its bit hard to find users that didn't perform any action on a movie yet. If you can use a side DB such like Redis you can pull this off very easily. With Redis data structures you can query which user hasn't liked/disliked yet and get the rest of the movie data from DynamoDB. But putting side database, Redis, to aside for now and going with only DynamoDB approach.

One approach could be when each movie arrives to DB (new movie) you can add them to each of the users with the action type `not-actioned-yet`. And now for all users you can query these very easy and very fast. (Now it knows where the data is ;) ) But this isn't right because if there are 10.000 users then for every movie you make 10.000 writes.

Another approach could be imagine you have item on a table that holds the date of the user's last 'get list of not-yet-actioned' query. Now, after some time user comes back for the same query and now you need to read that date and get all the movies that is added to your DB after that date. With datetimes as sort keys you can query movies starting from that date. Lets say, 10 movies added after users last query (these are definitely user hasn't actioned yet). Now you add these 10 movies to a table as an item `not-actioned-yet`. After this you will you have all the movies user hasn't actioned yet. 'not-actioned-yet' is also type like 'like, disliked'. From now on you can query for them easily.

**Example table structures:**

You can either use [sparse indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) or [time series table approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html) to separates new movies (in next 2 weeks) from others. This way you query or scan only them efficiently. Going with sparse indexes here

**Movies table**

```
| Id (Hash Key|Primary Key) | StartingDateUnix(GSI SK) | IsIn2Weeks (GSI) |
|:-------------------------:|-------------------------:|:----------------:|
| MovieId1                  |        1234567           |     1     
| MovieId2                  |        1234568           |     1    
| MovieId3                  |        001123            |     null
```

To get movies after unix 1234567 you have to query GSI with a sort key bigger than unix time.

**User Actions Table**

```
| UserId (Hash Key) | ActionType_ForMovie(Sort Key) | CreatedAt (LSI) |
|:-----------------:|:-----------------------------:|:---------------:|
| UserId1           |       no-action::MovieId1     |      1234567    |
| UserId1           |       no-action::MovieId2     |      1234568    |   
| UserId1           |       like::MovieId3          |      1234569    | 
| UserId1           |       like::MovieId4          |      1234561    |     
| UserId1           |       dislike::MovieId5       |      1234562    |
```

Using sort keys you can query for all the likes dislikes not yet actioned ... and you can sort them by dates. You can also paginate.

I have spent some time on this problem, because its also good challenge for me and i would appreciate a feedback. Hope it helps in some way

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I were to take this route, it sounds like I'd need to add a record, for every movie (400,000) for every user. With just 10 users that would be 4 million items. I know scale isn't a huge issue with dynamo; not sure though on the costs associated with that though as I'd have to pay for each item coming out as a read. When the user looks at their list of previous actions, I'd query for all like/dislikes which could be a lot of items and require a very high RCU at a large scale

Comment: I had thought about having a table, with Id as Hash, starting date as SK to store all movies. Each movie would have a number set containing the user id of each user who has taken action. That way I can potentially filter out movies where @Userid doesn't exist in that set. Then a second table with userid as hash, action-type as sort and a number set of likes and a number set of dislikes. Each containing movie ids they'd actioned on. Downside is I have to update two records on two different tables when an action is performed. There would be risk of errors causing things to get out of sync.

Comment: Another option is to store all movies in the dynamodb, and store all user actions. Take a dump of that data into a data lake and generate what the set of movies a user hasn't actioned on via data processing outside of dynamodb, and push the results back into dynamodb as the next set of movies available for a user. That process could run for several seconds after a user processes 30-50% of their current queue, to ensure their list of unprocessed movies never runs out.

Comment: I dont understand couple things now. Answering to your first comment. You dont add a entry for every user. You add them when that user comes to your for the movie list. This boils down to only active users. It wont be 4 million items I dont think so. Secondly, when a user queries their previous likes you dont query lots of items either. You just paginate. Its what every app do. You read only recent 25 items and wait for user to ask page 2, that is another 25 items. You can query dynamodb Sort Key with 'Begins_with' keyword, which will give you 'Begins_with(like::)' and there for only likes.

Comment: Answering your second comment. Whats the point of having a sort key when all the hask keys are unique? You cant query anything can you? I had practiced this 'listing in the same entry' approach and it is in many cases bad. With each manipulation you read/update the row and if the size is bigger than 4kb , which it will be very soon, you consume more and more capacity reading/updating one entry. DynamoDB recommends scattering data over indexes like sort keys I suggested rather than bundling them into the same item.

Comment: Answering your third comment.  I think a side process is your thing here. I wouldnt doing this what you with Redis or any fast db that will be responsible for identifying that a user hasnt actioned yet. Then let the dynamodb do the rest.